# Почему adb не стуртует при запущенном Genymotion?

Tags: android, genymotion, adb

Задача запустить React Native в эмуляторе. Genymotion стоит и даже работает, но при попытке в Expo XDE запустить проект на эмуляторе вылезает ошибка:

```
Couldn't start project on Android: ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
```

Если при этом попытаться получить список доступных устройств через

```
$ adb devices
```

сообщает вот что:

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037': Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
```

Если стартовать adb с выключенным Genymotion, то всё ок. Как их подружить?

Comment: В настройках Genymotion закладка ADB. Пропишите там путь до **вашего** sdk.

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Он и до этого ссылался на мой SDK.